# How do I programmatically compile and instantiate a Java class?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-loading

I have the class name stored in a property file. I know that the classes store will implement IDynamicLoad. How do I instantiate the class dynamically?

Right now I have

```
     Properties foo = new Properties();
    foo.load(new FileInputStream(new File("ClassName.properties")));
    String class_name = foo.getProperty("class","DefaultClass");
    //IDynamicLoad newClass = Class.forName(class_name).newInstance();
```

Does the newInstance only load compiled .class files? How do I load a Java Class that is not compiled?

Comment: You can do it but you need to use JDK, not JRE . https://medium.com/@davutgrbz/the-need-history-c91c9d38ec9

Answer (score 157, accepted):

> *How do I load a Java Class that is not compiled?*

You need to compile it first. This can be done programmatically with the [`javax.tools` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/package-summary.html). This only requires the [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) being installed at the local machine on top of JRE.

Here's a basic kickoff example (leaving obvious exception handling aside):

```
// Prepare source somehow.
String source = "package test; public class Test { static { System.out.println(\"hello\"); } public Test() { System.out.println(\"world\"); } }";

// Save source in .java file.
File root = Files.createTempDirectory("java").toFile();
File sourceFile = new File(root, "test/Test.java");
sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

// Compile source file.
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());

// Load and instantiate compiled class.
URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { root.toURI().toURL() });
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("test.Test", true, classLoader); // Should print "hello".
Object instance = cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); // Should print "world".
System.out.println(instance); // Should print "test.Test@hashcode".
```

Which yields like

```
hello
world
test.Test@cafebabe
```

Further use would be more easy if those classes `implements` a certain interface which is already in the classpath.

```
SomeInterface instance = (SomeInterface) cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

Otherwise you need to involve the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to access and invoke the (unknown) methods/fields.

---

That said and unrelated to the actual problem:

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("ClassName.properties")));
```

Letting `java.io.File` rely on current working directory is recipe for portability trouble. Don't do that. Put that file in classpath and use [`ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))  with a classpath-relative path.

```
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ClassName.properties"));
```

Comment: Just an off topic question. I get a null when I load the properties your way but I get the properties when I do it Foo.class.getResourceAsStream()? Could you help me understand your code? Thank you.

Comment: That properties file is apparently placed in the same package as `Foo` class. As said, you need to specify a classpath-relative path, e.g. `com/example/filename.properties`. But if you can guarantee that the properties file is always in the same package as `Foo` class, then `Class#getResourceAsStream()` is also okay. You'll only miss the ability to externalize the propertiesfile outside the application so that it can be modified without modifying/repackaging the application.

Comment: @BalusC: Sorry if I am redundant, but can I specify classpath before compiling the java file? If so, will need your guidance.

Comment: Is it possible to compile the classes in memory, get the resulting bytecode as a resulting byte array and store it somewhere else (e.g. on the network, or in a database) so that a custom classloader can retrieve it? (Instead of writing local files).

Answer (score 6):

In the same vein as BalusC's answer, but a bit more automatic wrapper is here in this piece of code from my kilim distribution.
https://github.com/kilim/kilim/blob/master/src/kilim/tools/Javac.java

It takes a list of strings containing Java source, extracts the package and public class/interface names and creates the corresponding directory/file hierarchy in a tmp directory. It then runs the java compiler on it, and returns a list of name,classfile pairs (the ClassInfo structure).

Help yourself to the code. It is MIT licensed.

Comment: What happens if the compilation fails?

Answer (score 5):

Your commented code is correct if you know that the class has a public no-arg constructor. You just have to cast the result, as the compiler can't know that the class will in fact implement `IDynamicLoad`. So:

```
   IDynamicLoad newClass = (IDynamicLoad) Class.forName(class_name).newInstance();
```

Of course the class has to be compiled and on the classpath for that to work.

If you are looking to dynamically compile a class from source code, that is a whole other kettle of fish.