# How to Run a java source code inside a program.

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Run Java Source Code within a Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965224/how-to-run-java-source-code-within-a-java-program)

Our group wants to run a java source code inside a java program/application, given that the syntax inside is error free. how can this be? would we still need to compile for errors? or is compiling inescapable?  Thank you ...

Just like netbeans can run its codes underneath.

Comment: sound like `eval ()` in python :D. btw, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string

Comment: Also, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class/2946402#2946402

Comment: this question has been answered in the above links already

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function java.lang.Runtime.exec(), [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaha%2Fjvlngex1.htm), and [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-run-another-application-from-java.html?page=2) is another one on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run a java (or another external) program from java code using the `Runtime` `exec` method, and how to read command's output and possible errors during execution:

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaRunCommand {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {        
            // run the Unix "ps -ef" command
            // using the Runtime exec method:
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

More details: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016