# Java class definition in runtime

Tags: java, class, runtime, definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I programmatically compile and instantiate a Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class)

How to create a new java class at runtime?

Comment: It is possible with BCEL but why would you want to do that? How would you use it?

Comment: @Balus, are you sure it's a duplicate? This question is about dynamically defining a class. The question you've linked is about dynamically creating an instance of an existing class.

Comment: @Grze: don't read only titles. The question, at least the answer, in question also also covers dynamically creating a class :) Edit: I've improved the title of the other question a bit.

Comment: What do you need it for? Perhaps what you really want to do can be done using anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @Balus: You're right. I read the title and the question, but didn't look at the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`Class<?> ClassLoader.defineClass(String name, byte[] b, int off, int len, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain)`

The problem is that this method is protected. So, you should extend class loader with your own class and call this method from there.