# Compile dynamically java class web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, wildfly-9

I'm developing a web application where I can import a java code, compile and then execute it. 
This class might have some imports from another libraries, which I added to my classpath.
Running it as a desktop application, it works, but running under wildfly 9.0.2 it doesn't find my classpath libs and so, I have errors to compile my code.

Do I have to change any setting on wildfly configuration? I tried my code with and without maven.

I'm using this lib to compile my code, and like I said, it worked using the app like desktop: https://github.com/trung/InMemoryJavaCompiler

Errors:

```
13:44:57,686 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) /br/com/project/webtest/service/CompileClass.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
13:44:57,686 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) import static org.junit.Assert.*;
13:44:57,686 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)                        ^
13:44:57,687 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) /br/com/project/webtest/service/CompileClass.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
13:44:57,687 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) import br.com.project.webtest.service.SeleniumService;
13:44:57,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)                                               ^
13:44:57,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)   symbol:   class SeleniumService
13:44:57,688 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5)   location: package br.com.project.webtest.service
13:44:57,689 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) /br/com/project/webtest/service/CompileClass.java:4: error: package org.junit does not exist
13:44:57,689 ERROR [stderr] (default task-5) import org.junit.*;
```

The error messages continues with all others import libs
and then, the classformaterror:

```
13:44:57,751 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-5) #{testController.action()}: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file: javax.faces.FacesException: #{testController.action()}: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

Edit:
I added using eclipse mars, under the Webcontent/web-inf/lib folder, added my libs and right click, add to build path.

Edit 2:
Class responsible for creating the code and get the result:

```
package br.com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TestController {

    public void actionParent() {
        String javaCode = generateJavaCode();
        Class<?> compile = null;
        try {
            compile = InMemoryCompilerTest.compile(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
                    "br.com.project.webtest.service.CompileClass", javaCode);
            System.out.println("Worked: " + compile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    public void actionClassLoader() {
        String javaCode = generateJavaCode();
        Class<?> compile = null;
        try {
            compile = InMemoryCompilerTest.compile("br.com.project.webtest.service.CompileClass", javaCode);
            System.out.println("Worked: " + compile);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    private static String generateJavaCode() {
        String java = "package br.com.project.webtest.service;\r\n" 
                    + "import static org.junit.Assert.*;\r\n"
                    + "public class CompileClass {\r\n" 
                    + " public CompileClass() {\r\n"
                    + "     System.out.println(\"Dynamically compiled\");\r\n"
                    + "     String text = \"Testing JUnit lib\";\r\n"
                    + "     assertEquals(\"Testing JUnit lib\", text);\r\n" 
                    + "     System.out.println(\"completed\");\r\n"
                    + " }\r\n" + "  public static void main(String[] args) {\r\n" 
                    + "     new CompileClass();\r\n"
                    + "     System.out.println(\"finish\");\r\n" 
                    + " }\r\n" 
                    + "}\r\n";

        return java;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        TestController c = new TestController();
        c.actionClassLoader();
        c.actionParent();
    }

}
```

I created a class which extends the lib and changed use parent classloader:

```
public class InMemoryCompilerTest extends InMemoryJavaCompiler {
    static JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

    public static Class<?> compile(ClassLoader parent, String className, String sourceCodeInText) throws Exception {
        SourceCode sourceCode = new SourceCode(className, sourceCodeInText);
        CompiledCode compiledCode = new CompiledCode(className);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(sourceCode);
        DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(parent);
        ExtendedStandardJavaFileManager fileManager = new ExtendedStandardTest(
                javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null), compiledCode, cl);
        JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = javac.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits);
        boolean result = task.call();
        return cl.loadClass(className);
    }
}

public class ExtendedStandardTest extends ExtendedStandardJavaFileManager{

    protected ExtendedStandardTest(JavaFileManager fileManager, CompiledCode compiledCode, DynamicClassLoader cl) {
        super(fileManager, compiledCode, cl);
    }

}
```

xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form>

        <h:commandButton action="#{testController.actionClassLoader()}" value="ClassLoader" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{testController.actionParent()}" value="Parent" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I tested passing parent classloader as you sugested but also didnt work.

The first class "TestController" executing from main method it works.

Edit:

I have added the following code where I can set the classpath with my libs:

```
// set the classpath
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();

        options.add("-classpath");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) parent;

        for (URL url : urlClassLoader.getURLs()) {
            sb.append(url.getFile()).append(File.pathSeparator);
        }
        options.add(sb.toString());
```

Executing as a Java application it returns:

```
[-classpath, /C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/build/classes/;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/InMemoryJavaCompiler-1.2.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/client-combined-3.0.0-beta3-nodeps.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/gson-2.3.1.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/guava-19.0.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/httpmime-4.5.2.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/jna-4.1.0.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/junit-4.12.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/phantomjsdriver-1.3.0.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/workspace_libs/cglib-nodep-3.2.4.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/annotations-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/catalina-ant.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/catalina-ha.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/catalina-storeconfig.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/catalina-tribes.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/catalina.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/ecj-4.3.1.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/el-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/jasper-el.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/jasper.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/jsp-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/servlet-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-jdbc.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-jni.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-spdy.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-util-scan.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-util.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/tomcat-websocket.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Apache%20Tomcat%208.0.3/lib/websocket-api.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/libraries/JSF%202.2%20(Mojarra%202.2.0)/mojarra-2.2.0-FCS/lib/javax.faces.jar;]
```

Executing as webapplication:

```
[-classpath, /C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/test/WEB-INF/classes/;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/test/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/test/WEB-INF/lib/InMemoryJavaCompiler-1.2.jar;/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/test/WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces.jar;]
```

How could I get the same result?

Comment: you should described how you added them to your classpath

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, edited. I added like always did. Right click add to build path. Also I tried using maven. The libs are exported to war project, but not found when dynamically try to compile.

Comment: please show also the code that you use to compile

Comment: @NicolasFilotto updated. Tried your answer sugestion but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it working.

I have to make that change mentioned by @NicolasFilotto, to use parent classloader when using a webapp.
After that, for JavaCompiler works, as I'm using external libraries it's necessary to pass my classpath like mentioned on my last edit.
Basically the code changed to:

```
public static Class<?> compile(ClassLoader parent, String className, String sourceCodeInText) throws Exception {
        SourceCode sourceCode = new SourceCode(className, sourceCodeInText);
        CompiledCode compiledCode = new CompiledCode(className);
        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(sourceCode);
        DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(parent);
        ExtendedStandardJavaFileManager fileManager = new ExtendedStandard(
                javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null), compiledCode, cl);

        // set the classpath
        List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();

        options.add("-classpath");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Enumeration<URL> resources = parent.getResources("/");
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL url = resources.nextElement();
            sb.append(url.getFile()).append(File.pathSeparator);
        }

        options.add(sb.toString());

        // execute the compiler
        Boolean call = javac.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, compilationUnits).call();
        if (call) {
            return cl.loadClass(className);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Using wildfly I had to change `URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) parent;` to `Enumeration<URL> resources = parent.getResources("/");`

Comment: This solution works for me like a charm!! Thanks!! I'm using Apache Tomcat 8. The only thing I had to modify was to remove the exclamation sign "!" at the end of every classpath. I don't know why, but in my classloader all the paths are excluded. I did this: `url.replaceAll("!", "");` to the string before append to sb, and it works fine!!

Answer (score 0):

@VictorBello I already implements these features in [Dynamic Loader](https://github.com/dvare/DynamicLoader). Even you can include Jar at run time in [Dynamic Loader](https://github.com/dvare/DynamicLoader)

```
public void DynamicJarCodeTest() throws Exception {
    try {
        StringBuilder sourceCode = new StringBuilder();
        sourceCode.append("package org.dvare.dynamic;\n");
        sourceCode.append("import org.apache.commons.math3.Field;\n");
        sourceCode.append("public class SourceClass {\n");
        sourceCode.append("   public String test() { \n");
        sourceCode.append("   return \"inside test method\";\n");
        sourceCode.append("   }\n");
        sourceCode.append("}");


        DynamicCompiler dynamicCompiler = new DynamicCompiler();
        dynamicCompiler.setSeparateContext(true);
        dynamicCompiler.setUpdateContextClassLoader(false);

        dynamicCompiler.addJar(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("commons-math3.jar"));
        dynamicCompiler.addSource("org.dvare.dynamic.SourceClass", sourceCode.toString());
        dynamicCompiler.build();

        Class aClass = Class.forName("org.apache.commons.math3.Field", false, dynamicCompiler.getClassLoader());
        Assert.assertNotNull(aClass);

        Class bClass = Class.forName("org.dvare.dynamic.SourceClass", false, dynamicCompiler.getClassLoader());
        Assert.assertNotNull(bClass);


    } catch (DynamicCompilerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getErrorList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hammad, but I can't get this working using your library. I just changed the "addSource" and "sourceCode" for my example and I get the error: `[{kind=ERROR, line=4, message=package org.junit does not exist}, {kind=ERROR, line=9, message=cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method assertEquals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  location: class br.com.project.webtest.service.CompileClass}]`. I Also tried adding the jar which is inside my lib folder but couldn't make work.

Comment: see this line 
package 'org.junit' does not exist mean junit dependency not found
include junit dependency in your build path or add jar from your library using add jar

Comment: I understood the error, the problem is that the junit lib is included in my buildbath and I got this error.

Comment: options inside DynamicCompiler get this path, which is correct `file:/C:/Users/dev/Automacao/workspace/test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.12.jar;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @victor-bello for the great solution.
My solution looks like this:

1. Need to copy all jar from your maven repository into one folder and distribute that folder with your app:
   [image: lib folder]
2. From them generate classpath for javac (stupid way):
   [image: classpath]
3. Copy InMemoryJavaCompiler code source from github and override:

   public class InMemoryCompilerTest extends InMemoryJavaCompiler {

   ```
   static JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

   public static Class<?> compile(ClassLoader parent, String className, String sourceCodeInText, String classpath ) throws Exception {

       SourceCode sourceCode = new SourceCode(className, sourceCodeInText);
       CompiledCode compiledCode = new CompiledCode(className);
       Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(sourceCode);
       DynamicClassLoader cl = new DynamicClassLoader(parent);
       ExtendedStandardJavaFileManager fileManager =
               new ExtendedStandard(javac.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null), compiledCode, cl);

       // set the classpath
       List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();

       options.add("-classpath");
       options.add(classpath);

       // execute the compiler
       Boolean call = javac.getTask(null, fileManager, null, options, null, compilationUnits).call();
       if (call) {
           return cl.loadClass(className);
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }
4. Call compile method:

   Class testClass = inMemoryCompilerTest.compile(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),"com.namespace.here.ClassName", someCode, stringBuilder.toString());