# JDK java executable vs JRE executable

Tags: java

I installed the Oracle JDK to /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_25 and set that directory to JAVA_HOME. 
JAVA_HOME/bin contains the java executable and JAVA_HOME/jre/bin contains another java executable.
The guide I followed said to add JAVA_HOME/bin and JAVA_HOME/jre/bin to the PATH but which is the correct executable to use and which will be used if I call java from the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Both JRE and JDK needed to run a jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12261128/is-both-jre-and-jdk-needed-to-run-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simplified overview of the differences between JDK and JRE

JRE means **J**ava**R**untime**E**nvironment : it contains only binaries for running java program

JDK means **J**ava**D**evelopment**K**it : it contains binaries for running java program + binaries to compile java source code (and produce a java program).

A JDK always contains a JRE inside (under directory `<JDK_HOME>/jre`)

The major difference between JRE and JDK is the *javac* program. (*javac* means ***java*** **c**ompiler)
(you will also find some other programs under the `<JDK_HOME>/bin` that aren't present under `<JDK_HOME>/jre/bin` : all of them may be useful to do java development - but in most case - useless to run a java program.

All programs that are in both locations (i.e. `<JDK_HOME>/bin`  and `<JDK_HOME>/jre/bin`) are the same, so it is not very important to make a distinction.

To answer precisely to your question : the *java* instance that will run when you execute a command line starting with *java* is the first instance of *java* found in your PATH system variable... just like any other program.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is earlier in the path for java - JAVA_HOME/bin or  JAVA_HOME/jre/bin.

If you take a look at the folder structure where jdk / jre is installed you would see that in the jdk/bin folder there are quite a collection of binaries such as java, javac, javap etc. The JRE would include java but not javac, javap etc. I am assuming this is linux and you downloaded the compressed archive and extracted that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really curious, you can write this to the command line:

```
where java
```

This will give the exact location of the executable. On my PC this gives me

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

which is a soft link for the system default runtime `java.exe` (in my case it is `C:\Program files\Java\jre 1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe`)