# Compiling a Jar with java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, java-compiler-api

For years I have been using an IDE (Eclipse) to compile my jar files for me, through the years  I have learned about how they work however I still don't fully understand how the jar knows where the main method is, I am also curious about how simple (or not) it is to compile one manually.

I have a (sort of) IDE I'm working on that will need to be able to compile and run a jar that includes both the file from the user and either a jar or a bunch of other classes (the API), I have seen some questions here mentioning Java `JavaCompiler` class but never giving demo code and there seems to be a next to no one that knows how to compile manually so I would like to contribute. So, how can I create a jar file using java code? Please provide demo code.

Comment: Here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file

Comment: "In Eclipse you can do it simply as follows :", "Compile your classes." - not what I am asking, "how can I create a jar file using java code?"

Comment: Java includes a fully functional set of zip file utilities (java.util.zip) that can be used to create jar files.  And there are some additional "nice to have" facilities in java.util.jar.

Comment: @LeeAllan- Did you look at the accepted answer on that question? It tells you exactly that and with a code example.

Comment: The only java code in that example is the file to be compiled, I need the code in which will compile .java files into a runnable jar.

Comment: Have you check out the explanation here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class

Then you can take a look at how to build JAR programmatically:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarOutputStream.html

Answer (score 4):

> I still don't fully understand how the jar knows where the main method is

That's the job of the [manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).

> I am also curious about how simple (or not) it is to compile one manually.

It's pretty straightforward - you use the [`jar` tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) after you've built the class files.

Let's do a full walk through.

Create a directory called `src` and a directory called `bin`. Under `src`, create a directory `demo` and a file called `Test.java` in that directory:

```
package demo;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Working!");
    }
}
```

Now compile the code:

```
javac -d bin src/demo/Test.java
```

(That will work on both Unix and Windows.)

Then create a manifest file called `manifest.txt` - it doesn't matter where it goes really, but I'll just keep it in `src` for the moment:

```
Main-Class: demo.Test
```

Now build a jar file:

```
jar cfm test.jar src\manifest.txt -C bin demo/Test.class
```

And run it:

```
java -jar test.jar
```

These days you can specify the entry point on the command line instead of building a manifest file yourself:

```
jar cfe test.jar demo.Test -C bin demo/Test.class
```

See the linked docs for more details on how to use the `jar` tool, and the potential contents of the manifest.

Comment: My IDE is written in Java and needs to compile for the user as explained. Could I get Java to run these Command Prompt commands? Or even if not create the necessary batch file?

Comment: @LeeAllan: You *could*, but you'd be a lot better off using the JavaCompiler class you linked to. Likewise you can use the classes in `java.util.jar` to build jar files programmatically.