# Obtain class reference from .java files for JUnit testing

Tags: java, junit

I have to write a program that run JUnit test case from a user interface.
I found that I can use `JUnitCore` class to run tests with method:

`junit.run(class files);`

but this requires the .class file containing the tests.
I need to obtain the .class files having only a path of a directory that contains the JUnit .java files but I don't know how to get reference to these and use them with the run() method.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

As it has been pointed out I don't need the .class files but an instance of Class for every java file in the directory. How can I get it?

**EDIT 2**

Just solved with parsing the path of file and using the `Class.forname(String)` method!

Comment: You are misinterpreting the docs; you should be passing instances of `Class` to this method.

Comment: How can i get it? If I try to use the .getClass() method from a file I get only the type object at runtime (File class in this example). Sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is the raw source (.java) files you're going to have to compile them before being able to reference them .class files.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class) should tell you how to do that programmatically

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as Oli Charlesworth pointed out I've misinterpreted the docs. I don't need anymore the .class files. My problem now is how to get an instance of Class from each .java file in a directory.