# How do I compile & instantiate a Java class from source programmatically when it has project dependencies?

Tags: java, reflection, dynamic-loading

[**This is great**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2946402/4019986), but what if the class in the uncompiled source should inherit from a project specific class (which is already loaded), and has other project dependencies?

As an example, say I want to give users of my software the ability to customize a class at run-time. I have an `abstract public class Customizable` and a custom `class StatusDetails` in my project, and lets say the user writes code in a file that looks like this:

```
import com.somepackage.util.StatusDetails;

public class Test extends Customizable {

    public Test(){
        System.out.println("Initializing Test");
    }

    @Override
    public StatusDetails getStatus(Object params){
        StatusDetails status = new StatusDetails();
        // Populate status based on params
        return status;
    }
}
```

How could I take that and instantiate it?

Comment: I don't really see a need for that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Bumbolt hopefully my additions make sense...

Comment: It kinda does. I will follow just because I'm interested to see how one would do this. Still I do not really see the benefit of this in any piece of software to do this at runtime against the many security issues. May be just me ;)

Comment: The goal is to make logic changes at runtime without having to bring the whole thing down and restart. Security may not be an issue in certain cases such as when the software is running stand-alone on the user's machine. Obviously, with this as a design parameter, the targeted users are developers. Sure they could blow things up, but it's their own system. They could blow things up just as easily by running their own program.

Answer (score 0):

First the class will need to be compiled, which means you will have to ship the required JAR files and provide a classpath.  To manage this, I highly recommend Apache's Maven, but the learning curve will set you back a bit. The good news is that after your learning curve, you will have a really good tool for building that is fully portable and ideally suited for managing Java projects.

Then you will need to put the output JAR file / classes on the class path of the running program and restart it.

There are other ways of going about it, each with a bit more difficulty.  You can avoid the restart by using a classloader, and have the program dynamically load the class in response to a user action.

You can avoid the externalization of the build chain by putting the build chain in the program itself, by calling the compiler tools interface, compiling the program and then using the custom classloader mentioned above to incorporate it into the running program.

The problems with such an approach (as mentioned above) are many.  Basically you're giving everyone a huge security hole to exploit.  For example, I could "load" code that trashes the filesystem, or opens network sockets for attacking other machines.

I recommend the separate build chain and manual configuration of the load, with a required restart.  It may make the user jump through a few more hoops, but it will keep the security holes from being easily exploited.

Comment: "You can avoid the restart by using a classloader, and have the program dynamically load the class in response to a user action." This is basically what I want to do. I don't really understand your suggested approach though. 

Also, the security holes you mentioned aren't an issue in certain instances. Particularly when the software is running stand-alone on the user's machine.