# Compiling text files in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a compiler that takes a `.txt` file and compile it using java. I've already made one, but that compile only `.java` files. I have used `JavaCompiler` class to do that.

Secondly .. to get file I've used this:

```
Class.forName("CLASS_NAME");
```

How to get a file that is external from the project folder?

Comment: What is a compiled `txt` file?

Comment: do you mean  "READING"?

Comment: I mean my program should accept the code as text file (.txt) and compile it. Currently it accepts .java files.

Comment: Yes Exactly .. Read a text file and compile it

Comment: I guess you're trying to ask the same question as this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2946338, is this true?

Comment: Are you making a compiler or using the java compiler? You have stated both

Comment: @BalusC  thanks for the help
Yes I guess that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JamesWierzba I'm using java compiler

Comment: `that takes a .txt file and compile it using java` for personal interest only, what is the benefit of namimg a java-file *.txt?

Comment: @Ben
That is commonly used for online judge systems, where the user submit his code as a .txt file and the system compile it.
An example for online judge: [link]( https://uva.onlinejudge.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Q: 
`How to get a file that is external from the project folder?`

A:

```
File aFile = new File("./../../folder1/folder2/test.jpg");
aFile = new File("C:/users/ABC/Desktop/test.png"); //no problems using / in Windows
aFile = new File("/home/ABC/test.pdf");

aFile = new File("D:/Folder");
aFile = new File(aFile, "file2.txt");
```

As long as none of these folders is your project-folder.

Comment: Thanks for the help.