# Tools to create new class during runtime

Tags: java

I am wondering what tools do I need to create new class based on user input (and named after it) in Java Application, with minimal usage of code? Example usage:

> ```
> Provide name for class: apple
> Class created: apple
> ```

Thanks

P.S
I dont need the code - I will handle it myself. I am just wondering which tools should I use.

**UPDATE**
I have found [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), though this only shows example of **predifined classes**. I would like to **define**
 new class.
 **UPDATE 2**
 In my case, I the new classes will inherit some of the properties of abstract class. Example: Abstract class Product, and new class 'ComputerProduct' that has access to the methods, and has its own implementations of this abstract class.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how you expect the new classes to behave and what you would do with them? What you're asking for is probably not what you want.

Comment: Do you mean this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class?

Comment: @RJFalconer, I've added extra update

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the [Bytecode Library](http://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries) for this purpose.
Most easy to use and which I prefer is [JavaAssist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/).

[BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) is open source with Apache 2.0 license, hence you may explore this as well.