# How can I write a public method in a class dynamically?

Tags: java

I am searching for this from many weeks but yet didn't got any solution. I want to write a method in a .class file which contains java byte code. I want to take  .class file as a text file and write text(method code). I can just write a java code in a .java file but in .class file, it works differently. So, I want to know how java machine reads the .class file and Is this possible to write a new method like this way.

Comment: You can use [bytebuddy](https://bytebuddy.net/#/) to generate bytecode at runtime, but if you want to write plaintext, you'll have to [decompile](https://github.com/pmikova/java-runtime-decompiler) the .class file, [write some plain text into it](https://spoon.gforge.inria.fr), then [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class) it again. As you can see, the latter is a lot more work.

Comment: https://supunsetunga.medium.com/introduction-to-java-bytecode-manipulation-with-asm-9ae71049c7e0

Comment: ByteBuddy is for creating classes but I want to modify an existing class file.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyR. , Your answer seems working. I will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lombok's [@ExtensionMethod](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod) might be what you're looking for.

You can add extra functionality to a compiled class.

Before using this on large-scale projects, read why this feature is considered "experimental".

```
// Because of this annotation "StringExtensions"
// will be applied to all strings referenced in class "LombokExperiment"
@ExtensionMethod({String.class, LombokExperiment.StringExtensions.class})
public class LombokExperiment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "hello";
        System.out.println(str.toTitleCase());
    }

    static class StringExtensions {
        // This is the example from Lombok's docs
        public static String toTitleCase(String in) {
            if (in.isEmpty())
                return in;

            return "" + Character.toTitleCase(in.charAt(0)) + in.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        }
    }
}
```

Will print `Hello`.
If you want another class, just replace the String.class at the class-annotation.

The first argument for the function, as mentioned in the documentation is the actual object which will be injected,
as you can see in the example, the object is `String` which corresponds to the `String.class` at the annotation.
You can then alter and return whatever you wish from the function.

Comment: Can you please give an example on how I can write a method in an existing .class file?

Comment: How can I remove closing tag from a compiled class ?

Comment: Yes it works on Java so it will work on Android,
What do you mean by 'closing tag' in a compiled class?